# How to query only part of database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Is there a way to query only parts of my database? Let me explain...i have a table, like shown on image below, and I have questions and answers there. A's are questions, and B's are answers. So, to avoid two databases, I created one. I need 8 answers to setText to 8 buttons, and in another row I need 8 answers to setText to other 8 buttons. So, with two db's I would just randomly pick a row, collection shuffle them, and setText to buttons, but with answers in the picture, I don't know how to do it. So, I need to randomly pick an id, select questions, shuffle them, setText to buttons, on the same row select all 8 answers, shuffle them, and set to other 8 buttons. Is there a way or do I need to create one more table and one more database helper class?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you may need to learn about SQL and Databases in general before working on your application

Comment: Any other useful comment? I think I AM in process of learning, why do you think I'm asking this?

Comment: You rarely needs more than **one** database for an application, so I think you are mixing *databases* and *tables*. And SQL is how you query tables in your database. You need to learn the basis before we can help you, the gap is too big

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's what I done so far and it works, but if there's is a better solution, correct me please. I skipped some irelevant parts of my code.

```
Button a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8;
    TextView pitanje;

a1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA1);
        a2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA2);
        a3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA3);
        a4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA4);
        a5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA5);
        a6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA6);
        a7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA7);
        a8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA8);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB2);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB3);
        b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB4);
        b5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB5);
        b6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB6);
        b7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB7);
        b8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB8);
        pitanje = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPitanje);

        nextQuestion();
    }

    private void nextQuestion() {

        TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();

        try{ 

            mDbHelper.open();

            Cursor c = mDbHelper.getTestData(generateWhereClause());

            mAnsweredQuestions.add(c.getLong(0));

            pitanje.setText(c.getString(1));

            List<String> labelsA = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> labelsB = new ArrayList<String>();

            labelsA.add(c.getString(2));
            labelsA.add(c.getString(4));
            labelsA.add(c.getString(6));
            labelsA.add(c.getString(8));
            labelsA.add(c.getString(10));
            labelsA.add(c.getString(12));
            labelsA.add(c.getString(14));
            labelsA.add(c.getString(16));

            labelsB.add(c.getString(3));
            labelsB.add(c.getString(5));
            labelsB.add(c.getString(7));
            labelsB.add(c.getString(9));
            labelsB.add(c.getString(11));
            labelsB.add(c.getString(13));
            labelsB.add(c.getString(15));
            labelsB.add(c.getString(17));

            Collections.shuffle(labelsA);
            Collections.shuffle(labelsB);

            a1.setText(labelsA.get(0));
            a1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            a2.setText(labelsA.get(1));
            a2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            a3.setText(labelsA.get(2));
            a3.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            a4.setText(labelsA.get(3));
            a4.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            a5.setText(labelsA.get(4));
            a5.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            a6.setText(labelsA.get(5));
            a6.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            a7.setText(labelsA.get(6));
            a7.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            a8.setText(labelsA.get(7));
            a8.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            b1.setText(labelsB.get(0));
            b1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            b2.setText(labelsB.get(1));
            b2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            b3.setText(labelsB.get(2));
            b3.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            b4.setText(labelsB.get(3));
            b4.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            b5.setText(labelsB.get(4));
            b5.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            b6.setText(labelsB.get(5));
            b6.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            b7.setText(labelsB.get(6));
            b7.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            b8.setText(labelsB.get(7));
            b8.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

    }
        finally{
            mDbHelper.close();
        }
```